# NoInitialContextException when tried to invoke Java code from Worklight

Tags: java, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a scenario where i need to connect to AD from worklight(not using LDAPLoginModule). I am trying to do so by invoking a java code from dummy http adapter. It is working as expected in dev environment; however when we move this to staging server it gives error.

Below is the code snippet and error:

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+url);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,  username );
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

ldap=new InitialLdapContext(env,null); (throws following Exception)
```

**javax.naming.NoInitialContextException. The calling code's BundleContext could not be determined.**

Any help on this will be very much helpful

Worklight Version : 6.2 
Liberty profile  : 8.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking up the error, it appears that was fixed in later releases of WebSphere. You should consider upgrading your application server. For more information see the following IBM document: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM90923